# Changing the function of dynamic links in info parts

Tags: axapta, x++

I am trying to let an info part's dynamic link work so that it only opens the queried values in a list on the new form.

Basically now, if i click Installation No. on the form part below.

[image: Related Installations]

Then this form opens up with all the Installations, not only the related Installations.

[image: This happens if the Id dynamic link is clicked]

What i want to happen is when the Installation No is clicked then the list should look like when the "more" button is clicked or like the image below.

[image: This happens if the "more" button is clicked]

It seems like this is the standard function but i want to know if there is a way to change it.

Does anyone know a solution to this or know if there is any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamic links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/bb394995.aspx) should work on info part forms provided prerequisites are met:

- A data relationship exists between two tables, usually as one-to-many (one parent row relates to many child rows).
- Each table has a field of the same extended data type.
- In the parent table, the extended data type field values uniquely identify each row.
- The extended data type has a relation defined on it for the field in the parent table.
- Each table is a data source for one of the two forms.
- The parent form contains a button that launches the child form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is not that the dynamic link is not working. It is working the way it is supposed to work, however i want the link to open only the same list that is in the query provided for the info part, the same way the "more" button works. I need to know if this is indeed possible and if it is, how is it implemented?

Comment: Have you found another info part that works that way? Maybe the corresponding information is found in `element.args().record()` or `element.args().lookupRecord()`. If the More button does not pass on the context, you may be out of luck.

Comment: I also think this is impossible to do. Everything i've tried and everything i've read lead to that conclusion. Thanks for your feedback.